# Google Maps iOS integration issue with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods

After Installing Google Maps API with Cocoapods, I tried to show a sample map centered at a random coordinates. That worked fine for me.

After That I tried to do some more complicated stuff on the map (add markers, polylines ... ) and I have a Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 error as described bellow :

[image: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7]

I verified if I didn't import some library but it seems that I've already imported all needed.

[image: Link Binary with libraries]

I verified also the "Other Linker Flag" field just in case there's something missing :

[image: Other Linker Flag]

Do you know a solution for that or at least the main reason for that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try adding -all_load to your other linker flags.

Comment: @72A12F4E : thanks. right now I have an other error : ld: 708 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a weird solution for this weird problem.

At the beginning, the content of the Podfile :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'vanilla' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

target 'vanillaTests' do   
end
```

What I changed to solve my problem, is changing the content of Podfile like below:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'vanilla' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

target 'vanillaTests' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

I do not know why, but this solved my problem. Note that I don't use Google Maps in my tests.